# Any suggestion of laser pointer for everyday life study of fluorescence?

Tags: optics, laser, home-experiment, quantum-optics, fluorescence

I want to buy a laser pointer to study fluorescence in my kitchen.

Any suggestion? What kind of laser pointer? What stuff for demonstration?

Comment: Fluorescence is always shifted towards the red, so red laser is of no use. Green pointer works well, many bright orange plastics will fluoresce. Blue laser is probably even better, but I haven't used one.

Comment: A UV laser is great for fluorescence, but I'm not sure if you can find a cheap one in a laser pointer package.

Comment: It looks like you can get 405 nm laser pointers for fairly cheap: [froogle.com: uv laser](https://www.google.com/search?output=search&tbm=shop&q=ultraviolet+laser&oq=ultraviolet+laser&gs_l=products-cc.3..0l2.3722.7268.0.7399.17.9.0.8.8.0.109.565.8j1.9.0.msedr...0...1ac.1.64.products-cc..0.17.598.ySCkYq3iRTQ).

Comment: I second the suggestion by Chris Mueller. That is what I used here: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/130758/79678.